# asp.net copying row from one datatable to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i have a datable and like this i have searched a datarow from the datable on the basis of some primary now i want to add that searched row to another datatable how can i achieve this please let me know

```
 DataTable findRows = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
 List<int> selectedList=(List<int>)ViewState["selectedList"];
 DataTable temp = new DataTable();

 foreach (int id in selectedList)
 {
   DataRow dr=findRows.Rows.Find(id);

 }
```

now i want it to add to datatable temp how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, when creating `temp` don't just instantiate it as a new `DataTable` but instead call `.Clone()` on `findrows` to create a structurally identical `DataTable`.

Second, use `.ImportRow()` on the second `DataTable` and pass it the row from the first `DataTable` that you'd like to copy.  This should create an entirely new row in the second table with the same values as the row from the first table.

Comment: DataTable findRows = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
                List<int> selectedList=(List<int>)ViewState["selectedList"];
                DataTable temp = findRows.Clone();
               
                foreach (int id in selectedList)
                {
                   DataRow dr=findRows.Rows.Find(id);
                   temp.ImportRow(dr);
                }

Comment: That looks to be about right, ya.  Sorry, I've been commuting for the past hour or more (picking up kids, etc.) so I didn't see these comments until now :)